# How to concatenate the value of iterator inside liquid tag (Jekyll)

Tags: ruby, for-loop, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I am looping through a Yaml object and need to append the value of 'i' to the address the proper object.

```
<div class="chapter">
  {% for i in (1..7) %}
    <strong class="title">{{ page.chapters.title + i }}</strong>
    <ul>
      {% for topic in page.chapters.ch + i %}
        <li>
          {{ topic }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The data:

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
chapters:
  title1: "CHAPTER 1: LEADERSHIP"
  ch1:
    - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    - Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    - Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.

  title2: "CHAPTER 2: THE EXPERIENCE"
  ch2:
    - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    - Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    - Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.
---
```

The part that doesn't work is this:

```
{% for topic in page.chapters.ch + i %}
```

I need the value of ch to be ch1, ch2, etc…

Comment: `page.chapters.ch` is a string or number?

Comment: This would work: {% for topic in page.chapters.ch1 %}, or this: {% for topic in page.chapters.ch2 %}, but I want to use a loop to increment those numbers.

Comment: Here, Information Architecture's questions are raising. What is exactly you goal ? Are you trying to publish a book ? Or, are you just trying to control single post display ? Can you explain a little more your data model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by updating the data model and creating a nested loop:

```
---
chapters:
  - title: "CHAPTER 1: LEADERSHIP"
   chapterList:
     - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
     - Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
     - Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.

 - title: "CHAPTER 2: THE EXPERIENCE"
   chapterList:
     - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
     - Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
     - Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.
---
<div class="chapter">
  {% for chapter in page.chapters %}
   <strong class="title">{{ chapter.title }}</strong>
     <ul>
        {% for chapterItem in chapter.chapterList %}
         <li>
            {{ chapterItem }}
         </li>
         {% endfor %}
     </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access YAML as Ruby associative arrays, but inline operations using the `+` operator won't work. You can remedy that by using the `append` filter.

Try this:

```
{% assign ch_key = 'ch' | append: i %}
{% for topic in page.chapters[ch_key] %}
    <li>{{ topic }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```